# Short story about a clone warrior who believes she's the original

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, clones

I read this in an anthology in the early-mid 1990s. Details are hazy, but the main character was a clone fighting in a conflict. She doesn't seem to realise that she is a clone, and believes herself to be the original and is still essentially living out the memories of the person she was cloned from.

She's eventually captured, but at the end of the story is rescued by another more advanced clone of the same individual but who looks almost angelic, surrounded by a swarm of tiny versions of herself.

I thought it might be an Orson Scott Card short story, but I haven't been able to find anything that sounds similar in his bibliography.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Except for the end this sounds a lot like Greg Bear's classic "[Hardfought](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41336)"

Prufax, the human clone pilot, is captured by a hydrogen-based alien that humanity is at war with.  The alien, a Senexi called Aryz, and Prufax eventually manage to communicate, and there is hope that the war might end.

Then a more advanced version of Prufax finds and kills Aryz, and the captured humans inside it too as corrupt.  The later Prufax is described as almost angelic, since all the systems of her "ship" are carried in what looks like jewelry.

Comment: Thank you, I think you could be right. I just need to find a copy of the story so I can read the whole thing!

Comment: @Leigh: https://archive.org/details/hardfought0000bear

Comment: Or, without a subscription, in *Asimov's*, February 1983: https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v07n02_1983-02/page/n107/mode/2up

Comment: This was definitely the story, thank you so much! Not sure where I got that ending from, though!